# Obtener datos de una tabla desde el controlador en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola como estan? tengo el siguiente dilema que no puedo resolver:
Tengo una tabla llamada tecnicos_servicios que almacena los campos:tecnico_id y servicio_id, y ademas tengo la tabla servicios que tiene un id, y un campo llamado SERVICIO, y finalmente la tabla llamada tecnicos con un id, nombre, etc...

La logica es que en la tabla tecnicos_servicios almaceno los servicios asociados a un tecnico, pero necesito mostrar el NOMBRE DEL SERVICIO (que esta en la tabla servicio)...

En el controlador tengo este codigo implementado:

```
  public function show($id){
        $asignacion = AsignacionMaterial::find($id);
        $detalle_asignaciones = DetAsignacionMaterial::where('asignacion_material_id',$asignacion->id)->get();
        $user = User::find($asignacion->user_id);
        $tecnico = Tecnico::find($asignacion->tecnico_id);
        $servicios = TecnicoServicio::where('tecnico_id', $tecnico->id)->get();
        $tecnico->servicios_tecnico = $servicios;
        //dd($user);
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($detalle_asignaciones as $detalle_asignacion) {
            //dd($detalle_asignacion);
            $material = Material::find($detalle_asignacion->material_id);
            $bodega = Bodega::find($detalle_asignacion->bodega_id);
            $detalle_asignacion->material = $material;
            $detalle_asignacion->bodega = $bodega;
            $total = $total + $detalle_asignacion->cantidad * $material->costo;

            //dd($servicios);
        }
        $asignacion->total = $total;
        return view('logistica.asignacion.show',compact('asignacion','tecnico','detalle_asignaciones','user'));
```

Mediante esta linea consigo traer los ids se los servicios asignados un tecnico x:

```
$servicios = TecnicoServicio::where('tecnico_id', $tecnico->id)->get();
```

Pero no se como hacer la relacion con la tabla servicios para poder mostrar el nombre de los servicios, solo consigo mostrar la relacion completa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La relacion entre la tabla tecnicos_servicios y servicios seria de 1-M (un tecnico puede tener uno o mas servicios y un servicio puede estar asignado a uno o mas tecnicos)

Modelo TecnicoServicio (Relaciones)

```
public function Tecnicos(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Tecnico');
      }

      public function Servicios(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Servicio');
      }
```

Modelo Servicio (Relacion)
No tengo defindo

Agradecido a todos de antemano

Answer (score 0):

La relación que planteas resolver es *muchos a muchos* (**guiándome por el nombre de tu tabla y las relaciones que definiste**), bajo ese contexto, entonces necesitas:

- Tener 2 modelos:

  - Modelo: **`Servicio`**
  - Modelo: **`Tecnico`**
- En cada uno de los modelos declaras la relación que los vincule del modo siguiente:

Modelo Tecnico:

```
class Tecnico extends Model
{
    public function servicios()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Servicio::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo Servicio:

```
class Servicio extends Model
{
    public function tecnicos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tecnico::class);
    }
}
```

Salvo que tengas algún requerimiento que lo justifique, no necesitas la presencia de un modelo para la tabla intermedia y de ser así entonces te sugiero te apegues [a lo que la doc. de Laravel recomienda](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models)

Llegados a este punto ya podemos construir la query

Luego entonces para poder mostrar por ejemplo todos los técnicos y sus servicios asociados, es tan simple como:

```
$tecnicosConServicios = Tecnico::with('servicios')->get();
```

O bien así:

```
$tecnicosConServicios = Tecnico::has('servicios')->with('servicios')->get();
```

Comentarios finales:

- Si deseas filtrar por ejemplo y solo obtener aquellos técnicos con al menos un servicio asociado lo consigues mediante: [*queying relationship existence*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)
- Te sugiero leas a [*detalle la doc. de Laravel*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) al respecto de las relaciones muchos a muchos, para que identifiques si requieres el paso de argumentos extra en las relaciones declaradas

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte beta, una consulta adicional, esto lo realizo desde el controlador cierto?

Comment: Las relaciones en los modelos y la consulta de forma común va en el controlador (*aunque no de forma estricta*)